# Vlookup to bring in value into lookup cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have two worksheets into a workbook named "Entry" and "Conversion." I would like to use a vlookup that references accounts beginning in cell E14 that brings back values from the Conversion tab into cell E14 and the cells below it.

This would be my vlookup formula: vlookup(E14,Conversion!A2:C300,False)
Can this be done in vba?

Comment: So you'd overwrite the value in `E14`? Sure, that's possible with VBA.

Comment: Your formula is missing the column number for the return value

Comment: Yes that is correct!! I would like to overwrite the value in E14 with the lookup value.

Comment: What does "in cells  below it" mean? All cells in E:E column, up to the last having value? Then, do you really want replacing the value in E14 with the one brought by VLookup? If so, will A2:C300 from "Conversion" sheet be absolute, or incremented with each used row?

Answer (score 1):

Please, use the next code. It is unusual to overwrite the cell used as lookup_value, so the code will return in F:F column. If you really want/need it to return in E:E, if you like its return, it is enough to write `sh.Range("E14")` instead of `sh.Range("F14")` on the last code line. But will you run the code only once? If not, what about the case when `VLookup` does not find a match (once)?. Anyhow, take care to have the F:F column empty, starting from F14:

```
Sub compareTwoMultipleRanges() 'array from Vlookup!!! 
    Dim sh As Worksheet, shConv As Worksheet, lastRE As Long, rngAC As Range, rngE As Range, Results
    
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    Set shConv = Worksheets("Conversion")
    
    lastRE = sh.Range("E" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Row 'last cell in E:E
    Set rngAC = shConv.Range("$A$2:$C$300")
    Set rngE = sh.Range("E14:E" & lastRE)
    
    With Application
     Results = .IfError(.VLookup(rngE, rngAC, 2, False), "Not Found")
    End With
    
    'drop results array values:
    sh.Range("F14").Resize(UBound(Results), 1).value = Results
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi - Thanks for the code.  I keep getting a Type mismatch error.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @Fred Blair Saying only that is not of any help... On which code line does it raise the error? But before that please, refresh the page (this one) and see if the code you try using is the one on the page. I made some modifications after I firstly posted it. If you cannot get it, do you have AnyDesk installed and accept a connection?

Comment: It wasnt showing the line in the code before but here you go: sh.Range("F14").Resize(UBound(Results), 1).Value = Results

Comment: @Fred Blair As sated in one of the above comments, your formula (in the question) was missing the column where from to return. I use a formula returning from the **second column**. **You must know where from the formula to return and adapt the code accordingly**... But even in such a circumstance it should return something. I asked above: ""do you have AnyDesk installed and accept a connection""? Without seeing what's happening in your real workbook/installation I can only guess... I tested the above code and it works as it should.